# How did it happen that the m'chaber came to be called that?

Tags: history, names, etymology, shulchan-aruch, authorship

The author of [*Shulchan Aruch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch), in his capacity as the author of *Shulchan Aruch*, is often called "the *m'chaber*", or "*ham'chaber*", literally "the composer" or "the author". (Obviously, many authors are called that when discussing their books, but the *m'chaber* is often called that even out of such context. For example, when discussing *halacha*, one might mention that the *Tur* holds a certain view while the *m'chaber* holds another and the *P'ri M'gadim* a third.) While of course *Shulchan Aruch* is an important and seminal work, there are other works equally important and seminal.

How did it happen that the *m'chaber* came to be called that?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that the Rama is called hagos,so it makes sense to call the Shulchan Aruch the Mechaber.He also took three shittos (Rif,Rosh,Rambam) and compiled the Shulchan Aruch,we still attribute the Shulchan Aruch to him.

Comment: Who calls the rama "the hagos"?

Comment: I think it was initially in the context of the Shulchan Aruch itself; the main text was written by the author (*m'chabeir*), as opposed to the many peripheral commentaries that were written by others. Likewise, in the context of other (including less widely studied) *s'farim*, other authors are also called "the *m'chabeir*." In my experience, moreover, that is a relatively uncommon appellation for R' Yosef Karo (cf. for example "the *Beit Yosef*") outside the context of discussing the Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: @Fred Indeed, many of the nosei keilim on the Rambam refer to him as such. Ironically, "the Mechaber" would probably cringe to discover that he is known as "the author [of the Shulchan Aruch]" and not "the author [of the Beit Yosef]".

Comment: @DoubleAA Well, the dynamics involved in studying the Shulchan Aruch lend themselves more readily to this naming convention. Although people could study supercommentaries on the Beit Yosef, it may have been a bit tedious and confusing to refer to the Beit Yosef that way in that context. (It's confusing enough how so many rishonim and early acharonim use idiosyncratic titles for other poskim).

Comment: @DoubleAA, why would he cringe?

Comment: @SethJ He would have thought the Beit Yosef was his _magnum opus_ while the Shulchan Aruch was just a review book for those who knew Beit Yosef.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard that the Bais Yosef was called The Mechaber since he combined (Chibur = connect) all the different Talmidei Chachomim in one location to come to a Halachic conclusion.

Comment: Was this meant as Drush or History?

Comment: @DoubleAA: I heard this from one of my Rabeyim years ago. Do not remember if there was a source and in what context it was said. I felt it was a worthy answer in spite of its ambiguity.